# NDK google sample keeps crashing at startup: native-activity sample

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to understand how to handle touch events from the C++ side for a graphics application I am writing in Vulkan.

Yet, when build and try to run this sample

https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/native-activity

The application won't start and exits with this exception:

```
2023-08-31 16:41:54.034 30823-30823/com.example.native_activity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.native_activity, PID: 30823
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nm1QPyiOSe1QJMjxiB2Lxw==/com.example.native_activity-CIsNQYJ7K-5YYyMZr7Y73g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~nm1QPyiOSe1QJMjxiB2Lxw==/com.example.native_activity-CIsNQYJ7K-5YYyMZr7Y73g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7828)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7577)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2400)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nm1QPyiOSe1QJMjxiB2Lxw==/com.example.native_activity-CIsNQYJ7K-5YYyMZr7Y73g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~nm1QPyiOSe1QJMjxiB2Lxw==/com.example.native_activity-CIsNQYJ7K-5YYyMZr7Y73g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
```

Anyone knows how to get pass this?

Here is the android studio I am using it:

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390, built on February 16, 2023
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1792M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    cidr.max.intellisense.file.length=1000000

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.plugins.visualstudiokeymap (221.6008.15)
    GLSL (1.21)
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This took a long time to resolve. But the answer came from the google forums.

remove from the AndroidManifest.xml file, the line below

```
android:hasCode="false"
```

then it works.